# Python strings and str() method encoding and decoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-2.x

I see that [the Python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) mentions `.encode()` and `.decode()` string methods. Playing around on the Python CLI I see that I can create unicode strings `u'hello'` with a different datatype than a 'regular' string `'hello'` and can convert / cast with `str()`. But the real problems start when using characters above ASCII 127 `u'שלום'` and I am having a hard time determining empirically exactly what is happening.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513027/encoding-gives-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-ordinal-not-in-range128) [overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026845/why-is-python-insisting-on-using-ascii) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error) [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239017/how-do-i-properly-work-with-unicode-characters-in-python-to-keep-from-getting-er) [regarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634715/python-decoding-unicode-is-not-supported) [Python's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436522/noob-queries-on-unicode-and-str-methods-in-python) [unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985486/utf-8-problem-in-python-when-reading-chars) [string-encoding/decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504200/how-to-decode-unicode-raw-literals-to-readable-string) [handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii).

**What exactly happens (how are the bytes changed, and how is the datatype changed) when encoding and decoding strings with the `str()` method, especially when characters that cannot be represented in 7 bytes are included in the string?** Is it true, as it seems, that a Python variable with datatype `<type 'str'>` can be both encoded and decoded? If it is encoded, I understand that means that the string is represented by UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, or some other encoding, is this correct? If it is decoded, what does this mean? Are decoded strings unicode? If so, then why don't they have the datatype `<type 'unicode'>`?

In the interest of those who will read this later, I think that both Python 2 and Python 3 should be addressed. Thank you!

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Python 3 does not have any of these issues: `str` can only be encoded and `bytes` can only be decoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only the case in Python 2. The existence of a `decode` method on Python 2's strings is a wart, which has been changed in Python 3 (where the equivalent, `bytes`, has only `decode`).

You can't 'encode' an already-encoded string. What happens when you do call `encode` on a `str` is that Python implicitly calls `decode` on it *using the default encoding*, which is usually ASCII. This is almost always not what you want. You should always call `decode` to convert a str to unicode before converting it to a different encoding.

(And decoded strings *are* unicode, and they *do* have type `<unicode>`, so I don't know what you mean by that question.)

In Python 3 of course strings are unicode by default. You can only encode them to `bytes` - which, as I mention above, can only be decoded.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I think that I may be best off porting to Python 3 and being done with it. I find the implicit decoding done in Python to be not only very 'unpythonic' (explicit is better than implicit) but also very confusing as the developer is not aware that such a conversion has taken place. Plus, it is decoding using the wrong encoding!