# How to see the bytes of a Python3 <class 'bytes'> object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

Considering that [the `bytes` type is not necessarily a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063502/python-strings-and-str-method-encoding-and-decoding), how can one see the actual bytes (ones and zeros, or octal/hexadecimal representation of such) of a `bytes` object? Trying to `print()` or `pprint()` such an object results in printing the string representation of the object (assuming some encoding, probably ASCII or UTF-8) preceded by the `b` character to indicate that the datatype is in fact bytes:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:16) 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> s = 'hi'
>>> print(str(type(s)))
<class 'str'>
>>> se = s.encode('utf-8')
>>> print(str(type(se)))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(se)
b'hi'
>>> pprint(se)
b'hi'
>>>
```

Note that I am specifically referring to Python 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bin`, `oct` or `hex` and access the byte using bracket notation:

```
>>> print(hex(se[0]))
0x68
>>> print(hex(se[1]))
0x69
```

Obviously a cycle will be better:

```
for a_byte in se:
    print (bin(a_byte))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Python string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to show the hexadecimal values of your bytes:

```
>>> se = b'hi'
>>> ["{0:0>2X}".format(b) for b in se]
['68', '69']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> s = b'hi'
>>> s
b'hi'
>>> print(s)
b'hi'
>>> for i in s:
    print(i)


104
105
>>> y = 'hi'
>>> for i in y:
    print(i)


h
i
>>>
```

Comment: This answer adds nothing new. Dek Dekku's accepted answer already shows how to iterate over the bytes with a `for` loop.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.